# what does -I or "unshift a path mean" in expresso?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, terminology

I'm not sure I understand what "unshifting a path" with -I means in expresso.  Does that mean if I run expresso with the switch as such

```
expresso -I myCode test/*
```

That when I normally use require statements in my tests in my test folder such as

```
models = require "../myCode/models"
```

That instead I can call the require like this?

```
models = require "models"
```

I thought that was my understanding but it doesn't seem to work as it gives me an "Error, cannot find module"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Overview**

Unshift basically just means "add an item to the beginning of a sequence of items".

So in this context, unshifting a path just means to add a path to the beginning of the sequence of paths.

The following cheatsheet explains a little more using arrays as an example.

**Quick Cheatsheet:**

The terms shift/unshift and push/pop can be a bit confusing, at least to folks who may not be familiar with programming in C.

If you are not familiar with the lingo, here is a quick translation of alternate terms, which may be easier to remember:

```
* array_unshift()  -  (aka Prepend ;; InsertBefore ;; InsertAtBegin )     
* array_shift()    -  (aka UnPrepend ;; RemoveBefore  ;; RemoveFromBegin )

* array_push()     -  (aka Append ;; InsertAfter ;;  ;; InsertAtEnd )     
* array_pop()      -  (aka UnAppend ;; RemoveAfter ;;  ;; RemoveFromEnd )
```